# Using a value from "iterate feature selection' to calculate a field

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I'm trying to streamline a model that identifies all zones that intersect each parcel in our Local Government Area (eg. Parcel x has Zone B1, B2 and E4). I am trying to make use of iterators in ArcGIS10. The problem is in bold italics below;

I have a Zones layer and a Parcels layer. I select all polygons of Zone A (using iterate feature selection) then do a select by location to get parcels that intersect those selected polygons. I now want to check if Field1 is empty, if it is, ***use calculate field to populate Field1 with the "Zone A" value used to select my zone in the first place.*** I then continue with some simple if-then-else logic and the model then iterates with Zone B.
[image: Screen Capture of my model]
I built a working version of this in ArcGIS 9.3.1 that works but it is extremely cumbersome and making small changes to the process is very time-consuming.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

P.S. I have no python experience and only a little VB knowledge but if writing an arcpy script is the only solution to my problem then I'm more than happy to start learning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say empty, I assume you mean "Null" or Empty like this: "".

Pass the ZoneName value into the "Calculate Value" model tool.  Then write a basic python function in the "code block" section of the calculate value tool.  If values are null:

def getField(field)
   if field is none:
       return "Zone A"

then call the function in the "expression" section of the Calculate Value tool like this:

getField("%ZoneName%")

Select String for "Data Type"

Now pass that into value into your field calculation as ("%Value%")