# Using Value from Iterate Feature Selection to Calculate Field in ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, field-calculator, iterator

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I have two polygon feature classes, an alignment layer and a parcels layer. I am trying to use ModelBuilder to create a tool that will do the follow:

1. iterate through groups in a single field of a polygon alignment layer (ie select and iterate through certain attributes in a field with same names such as "tunnel", "portal", etc)
2. Clip a parcel layer by each group
3. Populate a new field in the parcel layer called "EsmtType" with the name of each group (group is called "Value" in model)
4. Merge the clipped groups into one feature class

I have gotten steps 1 and 2 to function but I am stuck on step 3. I am not sure how I need to configure the "Calculate Field" tool in order to recognize the "Value" variant of the "Iterate Feature Selection" tool. I tried using the advice from [Using a value from "iterate feature selection' to calculate a field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17650) but I couldn't figure out how to implement it for my situation.

Here is the model I have thus far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdTcb.jpg

I would also like advice on how to implement step 4, I am not sure if it would require integrating a model within a model.

Comment: Could you please describe how you use the alignment layer?

Comment: Its a polygon layer that I am trying to use as the clip feature for my input parcel layer

Comment: Could you expand step four? Does the precondition prevent the merge from 'firing' too often? When I've run similar models, it has run a merge for each iteration, substantially increasing model run time...to an unacceptable level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to implementing step 3 was very simple. I actually didn't need to use "Calculate Value" before "Field Calculator" to make it work as @Arabella had suggested. The main piece of information that helped me was @Arabella telling me about preconditions. I set a connection between "Value" and "Field Calculator" as a "precondition" (which shows up as a dotted line), I then used the following expression in the field calculator: "%value%" and I set the expression type to PYTHON. This worked perfectly.

Below is a link to a screen shot of the functioning model (steps 1-3). I now need to implement step 4. The advice I have been given from the Esri forum is "To merge the clipped outputs you will need to use the [Collect Values tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000005000000) to collect the outputs of clip, make that output a parameter and drag that into a different model, the output of Collect Values would then be an input to the Merge Tool (data management)." I will test this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5dtQ.jpg

I have successfully implemented Step 4. I used the "Collect Values" tool to create a repository of my output clips. I then used the Merge Tool (data management) to create a single feature class, I made the output a parameter.

Tip: If you want to use this model but you dont want to iterate through selections of every record group then prior to running the tool, set a definition query (on the feature you want to use to clip by) to include only the attributes you want to iterate.

The final working tool:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I remember struggling with this in ModelBuilder as well, and the method I eventually came up with is this:

[image]

An expression is built using the `Calculate Value` tool with `Value` as an inline variable. It will return a string containing the current `Value` which can be used as the expression for the `Calculate Field` tool.

Comment: When I try to change the default expression of calculate value to anything other than the default, the connector between "value" and "calculate value" disconnects. I was also having this problem before I was using "calculate value" and just trying to connect "Value" straight to "calculate field", whenever I would alter the expression or code block the connector would disappear. Here is a screen shot showing the defaults, any idea what to do about this? http://imgur.com/0Ls9tZx

Comment: `Value` should be set as a precondition to `Calculate Value`. This ensures that the expression is constructed after the current value is updated, so the connector between `Value` and `Calculate Value` should be a dotted line. You can then fill in the Python code.