# Using the feature class name to populate a field in the features attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I'm trying to duplicate the model shown in [Using Feature Class "Name" from Iterate Feature Classes to Calculate Field with ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71340/use-feature-class-name-from-iterate-feature-classes-to-calculate-field-with-mo)

I have over 700 feature classes in a gdb and I need to use the name of the feature class to populate a new field within the feature class. I tried to duplicate the model above and I can't figure it out.

What is The Feature Type Parameter?

Comment: If you aren't moving the feature classes around, then you can remove the Feature Class to Feature Class step.  What specific error are you getting?  Name needs to be set as the prerequisite to Calculate Field, rather than an input, too.